# Advice on implementing multi language in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

I need some help in implementing multi language in my ng2 app.
For this, I need to do the following :

1) Change the URL based on the language. 
Example  `myapp.com/ar/jobs` or `myapp.com/en/jobs`

2) Load language specific CSS.

3) Translate all the text on the page.

---

1) To be able to change the URL based on the language I want to use UIRouterModule, but I am not sure if it's the best way. I came across UIRouterModule from this article http://cloudmark.github.io/Multilingual-Routing/

Can anyone advise me if there is a better way to change URLs based on language (example myapp.com/ar/jobs) ?

2) To load extra language specific CSS : I created 2 components 
    app.eng.component and app.arabic.component which are loaded from the 
    app.component based on an a condition
    app.eng.component and app.arabic.component have the specific CSS for the particular language.

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this. Can anyone help me on a better solution?

3) To translate I will create a pipe like this
https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-language-translation-in-angular-2-part-1

Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: For translation, I use this library and it works great https://github.com/ngx-translate

Comment: layout / minor fixes